# Query improvement in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, sequential

I need to write a hard query, and i need some help.

I have the following table (`MyTable`)

```
C1 int,
C2 int,
C3 int,
.
.
C79 int
C80 int
```

**Please note**: These columns names are fake. The real columns names are not similar. each column has it's own name which is not similar to any other column.

I have the following query (`queryA`):

```
select cnt / (select count(*) from MyTable)
  from (
    select c1, c2, count(*) over(partition by c1, c2) cnt
     from MyTable);
```

I need to run this query for each sequential columns: C(i) - C(i+1), C(i+1) - C(i+2)...In the query above, i ran it for c1 and c2.

In addition, i have two more similar queries such as the query from above. In the output table, each sequential columns will have 3 calculation from 3 queries.

The output table supposed to look like that (all of the column types supposed to be `float`):

```
c12A - calculation of query A for c1-c2
c12B - calculation of query B for c1-c2
c12C - calculation of query C for c1-c2
c23A - calculation of query A for c2-c3
c23B - calculation of query B for c2-c3
c23C - calculation of query C for c2-c3
.
.
.
c7980A - calculation of query A for c79-c80
c7980B - calculation of query B for c79-c80
c7980C - calculation of query C for c79-c80
```

I hope was clear enough. Any recommendation how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH t1 AS (
SELECT 'MYTABLE' nm FROM dual
),
t2 AS (
select rw, c1, c2 from (
    SELECT column_id rw, column_name c1, 
           lead(column_name) OVER(ORDER BY column_id) c2 FROM cols CROSS JOIN t1 
    WHERE table_name = t1.nm
  ) WHERE c2 IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT 0 rw, 'select rw,n/n_all from (select count(*) n_all from ' || nm || ') cross join ('  FROM t1
UNION ALL
SELECT rw, CASE WHEN rw > 1 THEN 'union all ' END || 'select ' || rw 
           || ' rw, count(*) over(partition by ' || c1 || ', ' || c2 || ') n from ' || t1.nm 
FROM t2 CROSS JOIN t1
UNION ALL
SELECT 10000 rw, ') order by rw'  FROM dual
order by rw;
```

You can generate the query string using Oracle dictionary `cols` (= `user_tab_columns`).

I used `cols.column_id` to define the "order" of the columns: `lead(column_name) OVER(ORDER BY column_id)`

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried to run this query, and i got the following error: "RW": Invalid identifier (line 11). This query is too complicated so i didn't manage to fix this issue.

Comment: @Omri Sorry, there was a small mistake. I've updated my answer

Comment: Thanks. Now the query doesn't return an error, but the output looks broken. I got two columns: the name of the first one is RW which including number from 1 to 81, and the value of the last row jump to 10000. The second column has values that looks like a queries. for example: "union allselect22 rw, count(*) over partition by...". I checked several times and my query is identical to yours. Any idea? –  Omri 6 mins ago

Comment: BWT, is this query possible with FOR loop? (each iteration will take the next column).

Comment: @Omri This query just returns the sql string which you can run to produce the results. It doesn't return the output you need.

Comment: OK. I Understand. I'll try it tomorrow. I'm not infront the DB. BTW,as i wrote above, the query including strings like "allselect22". It's looks like an issue. I'll check it tomorrow and let you know the results. Thanks!

Comment: unfortunately, I didn't manage to use the query. I ran your query and got two columns: one with numbers from 1 to 82 (and the last one jumps to 10000). The second column looks like a query, so I copied this column into a new worksheet, I tried to run it with no success. I tried to replace the string "allselect32" with "all select" or "all select 32" and it didn't help. This string looks strange.